# Installing GATE on my computer

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse

I'm trying to installe a program called [GATE](https://gate.ac.uk/download/) on my computer (Ubuntu 12.04).  When downloaded I get a .jar file, but there install instructions seem unclear to me.  Can anyone lend me hand in getting this to work.  I have Java 8 installed already and am using Eclipse.

Comment: There's instructions on the website - open a terminal in the directory into which you downloaded the file, and run `java -jar gate-8.2-build5482-installer.jar`.

Comment: @JonasCz Thank you!  I'm relatively new to LInux and was quite confused with what to do with the file.  This worked.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you have a .jar with JDK present in your system, you can run it as `java -jar <jarfile>.jar`. This is independent of the OS you are using.